# Am I Too Young To Publish?

Tags: creative-writing, self-publishing, first-time-author, young-author, dark-fantasy

I am turning 14 years old soon and currently working on a story called "*Royal Wings*" that I would love to get published someday. When it is completed it will be intended to be a Young Adult/Teen Dark Fantasy story. However, as I am finding myself climbing deeper and deeper into the plot, characters, and overall story, I am constantly asking the same question. "Am I too young to publish?" "Do I have to wait until I am 18 in order to publish this story?" Along with many more. So, that's what I am here to ask you.

**Am I too young to publish? If so, how long do I have to wait? If not, how can I get my story out there and build up an audience before it makes its 'debut'?**

If you also want a preview of Chapter 1, here is a [link](https://plotfactory.com/stories/preview/df166adc-e47e-4018-a898-dd4eeb1c6be0) (I have not fully edited it yet)

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE! This is a question we receive quite frequently, so I'm confident that the linked question (or one of its many duplicates) will answer yours. Since you included a link to part of your story, I should mention that while we don't accept critique questions, we *do* have a [critique chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115415/beta-reviewers-reviewing) where you can post stories and request feedback, which may be of interest to you.

Comment: You might have to accept that even if it's possible to publish at a young age, your first (second, third...) book might not be the one that gets published (it usually isn't, even for adults). That said, your writing is much better than mine was at your age, and I have high hopes for your future success :) Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Legally at least in the US, you'll need to be at least 18 years of age for a contract to be binding.  That said, a parent or guardian may be able to accept on your behalf.  However, this will likely vary on a publisher-by-publisher basis.

Comment: Okay, could you explain to me what a contract of binding is, what it does, and what it allows you to do?

Comment: @Farren   This no real thing called a contract of binding - it sounds like some magical spell in a fatasy story.  A binding contract is one which is legally bindng on the two parties, so that they are legally obligated or bound to fulfill the terms of the contract.  I note that many child actors sign legally binding contracts - or their parents or guardians sign the contracts  for them.  I presume that the same thing happens with the smaller group of child and teenage authors.